# Экран загрузки перед отображением фрагмента

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Хотелось бы перед отображением необходимого фрагмента показывать экран загрузки (без `Dialog`) до того момента, пока данные не будут загружены. Сложность именно в том, что это нужно реализовать как фрагмент, на место которого уже будут выведены данные. В голову приходят только костыли. Когда гуглил, наткнулся на эту библиотеку:

https://github.com/johnkil/Android-ProgressFragment

Но она уже давно не обновлялась, да и засорять проект библиотеками тоже не хочется. Возможно, кто-то знает опитимальный способ получения такого эффекта?

Заранее спасибо.

**UPD**

Возможно, не совсем очевидно, но я хочу получит подобный эффект

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: зачем выдумывать костыль с загрузочным фрагментом, если можно просто показывать прогресс бар, а когда всё загрузится показывать layout

Comment: @SviatVolkov показывать `Dialog` - значит, блокировать управление. Да и выглядит не очень. Я хочу именно показывать пустой фрагмент с загрузочным кругом (звучит тупо) по центру до показа основной разметки.

Comment: @ahgpoug, Прогресс бар можно показывать в основной разметке, без диалога.

Comment: вы просто делаете FrameLayout в котором лежит ваш основной лейаут и прогресс бар. когда идет загрузка у layout'a visibility = gone когда загрузилось ставите visible. не надо никаких диалогов. диалоги вообще для другого были придуманы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Размещаете во фрагменте прогресс бар и контейнер с контентом, который изначально скрыт:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/loading_progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone">

    </FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Когда данные будут загружены, скрываете прогресс бар и показываете контейнер с данными.

Comment: Проблема в том, что в моем случае используется `CoordinatorLayout` c `CollapsingToolbarLayout`. Назначить его в контейнер я не могу. Вообще, у меня сейчас такие костыли: при загрузке фрагмента я проверяю факторы: подключение к сети и наличие данных. Перед методом `inflater.inflate` я проверяю это все и затом уже передаю в `inflater` необходимую разметку. Вот в момент, пока разметка еще не назначена, но загрузка еще не завершилась, мне и нужно показать `ProgressBar`. Пока смутно представляю, как это сделать.

Comment: @ahgpoug, `Назначить его в контейнер я не могу` -- Почему? В любом случае, Вы можете запихнуть куда-то прогресс бар.

Comment: Насколько я прочитал, `CoordinatorLayout` не очень хорошо работает с контейнерами. После того, как я назначил его во второй `FrameLayout`, он криво отрисовался.

Comment: @ahgpoug, Покажите [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Уже решил свою проблему. Вместо `FrameLayout` использовал `include`. Включил все 3 фрагмента в одну разметку и делаю видимым тот, который подходит под условия. Спасибо за наводку.